# Export whole excel sheet with chart to png

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

Say if you got a fancy excel sheet with chart and numbers, is there a way to export what you see into a PNG or some image file?

I tried something:

- 1 Excel=>PDF=>PNG: doesn't work; crop by page (I didn't try to change the page size to ridiculously large, which might solve the problem)
- 2 Excel=>HTML=>PNG: kind of works, but the fonts are gone for some reason
- 3 Screenshot: my screen resolution is limited though..

I just like to know if there's a more straight forward way to export the whole sheet to image instead of thru exporting to HTML first..

---

Below are some screenshots of the 3 ways:

1. Excel=>PDF=>PNG

[image: PDF_PNG]
(too many images for a new user)

2. Excel to HTML: not too bad. I will need to use something to save whole webpage into one image file (available in chrome and firefox). Downside is the conditional formatting / number bar is gone.

[image: Export to HTML]

3. just screenshot: okay, that's just a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem with #1 (export to PDF), simply change the "**Page Layout**" settings for your document.

For Excel 2007/2010 (and should be the same in 2013... I think), do the following:

1. Go to the "**Page Layout**" menu/tab.
2. Select the "**Page Setup**" settings (little arrow icon in bottom-right of the "Page Setup" section).
3. In "**Scaling**", set "**Fit to**" 1 by 1 page.
   [image]
4. (Here you can also adjust any quality and page size settings as you require, and in the next tab, "Margins", you can reduce the margins to also help make the PDF look better.)
5. Now export/save-as to PDF and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

PDFCreator, despite its name allows you to print to a PDF, or one of a half dozen picture formats including PNG.  Each format has many settings you can tweak to adjust its appearance.

Make sure you decline any 3rd party software offered during the install, if any.

[pdfforge.org](http://www.pdfforge.org)
[image]

Comment: It would be great if it supports mac :(